# Making a range-plot using ggplot: R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a range-plot (but with a bar instead of lines). I need help with a couple of things:

Here's the graph I have so far:

```r
df <- structure(list(value = 35), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(df, aes(y = value, x = "")) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.2, fill = "salmon") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 35)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Anxiety Score") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.9, xend = 1.1, y = 15, yend = user_value), 
               linewidth = 5, lineend = "butt") +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme_Publication() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Here's what the graph looks like:

[image: Anxiety Score]

1. I want the graph to start from the minimum value, instead of 0. How do I rescale the Y-Axis so that it starts from, say, 7 instead of 0? I tried changing `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 35))` to `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(7, 35))` but that just gave me a blank graph.

The end graph that I have in mind looks something like this:

[image: Ideal Anxiety Graph]

I can get the text using `annotate` but I'm wondering if I can simply have a scale that goes from
7-35 for this graph hugging the graph below

2. How do I reduce the distance between the title and the graph? I tried `theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = -1.5)` but the position didn't change. I tried with a bigger value as well but no luck.

Comment: To zoom in on ggplot2 geoms, use `coord_cartesian`; if you do that using `scale_x_continuous` or `scale_y_continuous` it will filter out any geoms not entirely within the range, which is why you see a blank graph. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#zooming

Comment: This also looks like what is sometimes called a "bullet chart", e.g. https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-11-29-bullet-chart-variants-in-r/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747833/create-bullet-graph-using-ggplot2-or-plotly-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theme(aspect.ratio = ...)` to give your whole plot a particular aspect ratio. This will make your title come down closer to the bar. It makes it easier to reason about plots if you avoid flipping co-ordinates. In addition, I would use a super-thick segment instead of a bar here. By setting `expand = FALSE` inside `coord_cartesian` you can get a tightly fitting x axis. The breaks can be set exactly as desired with `scale_x_continuous`

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(min = 7, value = 15, max = 33) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = 1)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), lwd = 100, color = "salmon") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value), lwd = 10, alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 2), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 33)) +
  ggtitle("Anxiety Score") +
  theme_void(base_size = 25) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/5,
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.length.x = unit(5, "mm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20)),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]