A 1-D number line/boxplot style chart in R
I am trying to generate a SIMPLE rendering to show the x-range of values as compared to thresholds (red, yellow, green). As inputs, I have lists of numbers representing the number that should be at the leftmost point on the bar, and the number that should be on the rightmost point of the bar:
x1 <- c(44, 73)
boxplot(x1, ylim=c(0,100), horizontal=TRUE, boxwex=0.2)


Ideally, I would be able to produce something that looks like this, with a threshold of red in the background for numbers from [0 to 48), yellow for [48 to 69], and red for (69 to 100]. Ideally there would also be a ggtitle style title.

I have already tried several options with plotly, ggplot2, and stripchart but all fail to generate anything close to my target. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've seen this type sometimes called a "bullet chart," e.g. https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-11-29-bullet-chart-variants-in-r/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747833/create-bullet-graph-using-ggplot2-or-plotly-in-r

You could use the shapes argument in layout for a plotly graph like this:
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

lims <- local({
  lims <- c(0L, 48L, 69L, 100L)
  tibble(left = head(lims, -1L),
         right = tail(lims, -1L),
         color = c("firebrick", "darkorange", "forestgreen"))
})

shps <- pmap(lims, function(left, right, color) {
  list(
    type = "rect",
    fillcolor = color,
    line = list(width = 0),
    x0 = left,
    x1 = right,
    y0 = 0,
    y1 = 1,
    layer = "below"
  )
})

shps <- c(shps,
          list(
            list(
              type = "rect",
              fillcolor = "#000",
              line = list(color = "#fff", width = 2),
              x0 = 44,
              x1  = 73,
              y0 = .35,
              y1 = .65,
              layer = "below"
            )
          )
)

plot_ly(width = 1000, height = 200) %>% 
  add_text(x = 60, y = .5, text = "Add a Label", textfont = list(color = "#fff")) %>% 
  layout(shapes = shps,
         xaxis = list(ticks = "outside", zeroline = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = TRUE, showgrid = FALSE,
                      zerolinecolor = "#000")) 


